# How to make a custom error message in zod?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, react-hook-form, zod

I'm trying to write a custom error message for zod validation.

This is my schema object, which I passed in the error message.

```js
const schema: ZodType<FormData> = z.object({
    firstName: z.string().nonempty(),
    lastName: z.string().nonempty(),
    email: z.string().email().min(5).nonempty(),
    pin: z.string( { invalid_type_error: "Must contain 4 digitsss "}).nonempty().min(4, "Must be 4 digits").max(4, "Must be 4 digits").regex(pinPattern),
    phoneNumber: z.string().nonempty().min(11),
    password: z.string().min(8).regex(Passwordregex).nonempty(),
    confirmPassword: z.string().min(8).nonempty(),
  }).refine(data => data.password === data.confirmPassword, {
    message: "Passwords don't match",
    path: ['confirmPassword']
  })
```

[image]

I've tried the string replace method, but I'm not getting my desired result.

```
 {errors.
<span className='text-xs font-medium text-[#DC2626]'>{errors.firstName.message?.replace('String', 'First Name')}</}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import { ZodError, ZodIssue } from 'zod'

const formatZodIssue = (issue: ZodIssue): string => {
    const { path, message } = issue
    const pathString = path.join('.')

    return `${pathString}: ${message}`
}

// Format the Zod error message with only the current error
export const formatZodError = (error: ZodError): string => {
    const { issues } = error

    if (issues.length) {
        const currentIssue = issues[0]

        return formatZodIssue(currentIssue)
    }
}
```

And wrap your validations code in trycatch statement:

```
 try {
      ...your code here  
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        throw new Error(formatZodError(error))
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a custom message in zod by passing an object with the structure `{  message: "Custom error message here" }` as an argument.

Note that in newer versions of Zod, `nonempty()` is deprecated, and you should instead use `min(1)` [Source](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/discussions/2847).

In your code above, to show an error that the First Name is required can be accomplished as follows:

```
const schema: ZodType<FormData> = z.object({
  firstName: z.string().min(1, { message: "First Name is required" })
});
```

If your field has a requirement for a minimum number of characters, you can chain a second `.min()` with the min number and respective error message if user enters less characters as the arguments.